# Want to display last 3 posts on the homepage

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, web

So i have rails app where all posts are displayed on /posts, which is where I want them. There, I have 10 posts per page. But, along with this page - i would like to take the last three posts and display them in a div on the root page.

Not sure where to start.

Thanks

Comment: what do you mean by the last three posts?

Comment: it's a photo site. So the last 3 photos that were uploaded.

Comment: did any of the answers help you?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
%div
  -Post.last(3).each do |p|
    %h1= p.title
    %p= p.author
    %p= p.content
```

`Post.last(3)` returns the last 3 posts that you're looking for. Hope this helps.

p.s. you may want to refactor this by moving the `Post.last(3)` into a variable in your controller like `@latest_posts = Post.last(3)`and iterate over that.

Comment: Note that `last` will return the results in ascending order.

Answer (score 1):

The `last` finder method will return the results in ascending order. If you want to return the results ordered by `created_at` in descending order, here's how I would approach it (unit test included).

**app/models/post.rb**

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  def self.recent(max = 3)
    limit(max).order(created_at: :desc)
  end
end
```

**spec/models/post_spec.rb**

```
RSpec.describe Post, type: :model do
  describe ".recent" do
    it "returns the most recent" do
      first_post  = Post.create(created_at: 3.days.ago)
      second_post = Post.create(created_at: 2.days.ago)
      third_post  = Post.create(created_at: 1.day.ago)

      result = Post.recent(2)

      expect(result).to eq([third_post, second_post])
    end
  end
end
```

In your controller(s):

```
@recent_posts = Post.recent
```

In your view:

```
<div id="recent-posts">
  <ul>
    <% @recent_posts.each do |post| %>
      <li><%= post.title %></li>
    <% end %>
  </ul>
</div>
```

If you want to reuse the view code, put it into a partial and render that in your view(s).

Comment: The way the test is written you are assuming that each post was created a day after the other. Shouldn't the test be more general, by testing to see if the created date for each of the three posts are less than/greater than each other (depending on if sorting by ASC/DESC)?

Comment: These `created_at` dates are arbitrary. The purpose of the test is to ensure the expected output of `Post.recent`. In this case, that the most recent posts are returned. The kind of granularity you mention would be a unit test on `order` within ActiveRecord.